# WPF webbrowser "document modified" alert

Tags: wpf

I am hosting a WPF webbrowser control in a WPF page.The webbrowser displays a WORD document which i display using webbrowser Navigate method. Now if i make any changes to the word document and then without saving i navigate to a different page i get a WORD message saying that **"The document has been modified. Do you want to save the changes?**".

I do not want to display this message as we have our own way of detecting changes and prompting the user if he wants to save or not.I should also mention that when i navigate away from the page i set the browser to "about:blank" so that WORD releases the handle to the file before navigating away.

I have tried the following options but it didn't solve my problem.

1. wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WORD.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
2. wordDoc.Saved = true;

I have a method "SetBrowserDocumentAlerts" where i have tried one of the above two mentioned options and i call it after navigating to "about:blank"

Please also note that i am not allowed to Quit the wordApp or close the wordDoc. It gives a error that this operation is not available as WORD is in use in another application.

Please suggest how i can stop the above alert message from WORD.